# How do you succed to Error 65 with the new version of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a problem with my xCode , i can't run the simulator since i update the new version (14.1)

i have a code 65
[image]

And when i'm trying to lucnh it with x code i have a multiples errors like that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences in Xcode and delete Derived data. Click arrow in red square and delete derived data
folder and emtpy your trash
[image]

Comment: the error coming back even after delete the derived data

Comment: you sure you added your podfile correctly or made pod install ?